# magento 1.7 language code issue

Tags: magento, currency

I have Magento store (1.7-community) with two store views.
On English side prices look like **$999,99**. On french side prices look like **999,99 $CA**.
I would like to get rid of CA.

in \lib\Zend\Locale\Data\fr_CA.xml
currency pattern looks like this

```
<pattern>#,##0.00 ¤;(#,##0.00 ¤)</pattern>
```

I tried changing this and even removing the section.  Flushed caches and deleted var/cache.  I am not even sure where CA suffix comes from.

But it does not go away.

Is there an over-ride, Is there a database table that can be cleared?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have configured the currency wrong? It might be canadian dollars you have now instead of US dollars. Have a look at the configuration.

Answer (score 0):

If the locale of your store view is set to `French (France)` rather than `French (Canada)` you will see this.  I just stumbled across it because the fr_FR translation is more complete than the fr_CA one and so I often use it instead and didn't consider issues like this.